# IIS url rewrite Rules With domain change and https

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

I used below code for http to https redirect, but don't know how to update domain and https at same time with multiple rules.

Thanks for your help

```
<!--Examples-->
    Example 1:
    
    input          : http://prodServer/MyApplication        
    Expected Output: https://prodServer.mycompany.com/MyApplication
    
    Example 2:

    input            : https://prodServer/MyApplication        
    Expected Output: https://prodServer.mycompany.com/MyApplication
    
    Example 3   
        
    input            : http://prodServer.mycompany.com/MyApplication        
    Expected Output  : https://prodServer.mycompany.com/MyApplication
```

code

```
 <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
              <rules>
                <rule name="httpsRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked for me with

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^prodServer$" />
 </conditions>
```

instead of

```
<conditions>
     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="prodServer" />
 </conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

We just write two URL rules for the requirement. One for forcing the HTTP request to https request, another for converting the hostname to the actual server name.

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
    <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{https}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Myrule2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="prodServer" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://prodServer.mycompany.com/MyApplication" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

Note: `StopProcessing` flag has no influent on the Redirect action, thereby these two rules will be performed properly on the server-side when an Http request received.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: url got changed, but site is not working after this changes, error message is " this page isn't working, redirected you too many times". i tried with example 1 link as in question.  Thanks

Comment: I doubt if the URL rules applies correctly.  Please clear your local cache and confirm it in a private browser window.  The URL rules works properly on my side, moreover, I suggest you test each rule individually.